# how to attach onclick event to an array of elements (mootools)

Tags: javascript, events, mootools

Is there a syntax for the following thing:

```
$$('.a-lot-of-elems').addEvent('someevent',somefunction);
```

Comment: That should just work. The element of course should support the event.

Comment: ... Although I'm not sure if this works for 1.1.2. What version are you using?

Comment: @Htbaa I am using the latest version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off - the following will work just fine.

```
$$(selector).addEvents({
    click: fn
});
```

Don't use **for**, to iterate through an element collection, use **each** instead:

```
$$(selector).each(function(el){
    el.addEvents({
        click: fn
    });
});
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/EPYBx/

Answer (score 1):

You are just missing the event type.

```
var someFunction = function(e) {
  alert('clicked!');
}

$$('.a-lot-of-elems').addEvent('click', somefunction);
```

Alternatively, you can use

```
$$('.a-lot-of-elems').addEvent('click', function(e) {
  alert('clicked!');
});
```

Comment: My bad, I meant to give a general example to what I need.

Answer (score 0):

something like

```
var elements = $$('.a-lot-of-elems')
for(var i = 0 ; i < elements.length ; i = i + 1)
{
  elements[i].addEvent(somefunction);
}
```

should do ya!

Comment: $ is used to fetch an element by id. This isn't going to work. You should use $$ to retrieve all elements matching the selector.

Comment: @thecoshman thanks, I am familiar with this way, I am looking for a shorter way to write this.